# Read value from file using a shell script

Tags: git, bash, shell, sed

I have a `Jenkinsfile` which I would like to read some values from within a shell script.

The section of the file is

```
-- Jenkinsfile
stage ('Setup Vars') {
  switch(BRANCH_NAME) {
    case 'develop':
      env.ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH = 'develop'
      env.HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH = 'master'
      env.FEATURES_BRANCH = 'master'
    break
    case 'master':
      env.ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH = 'develop'
      env.HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH = 'master'
      env.FEATURES_BRANCH = 'master'
    break
    default:
      env.ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH = 'feature-branch'
      env.HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH = 'feature-branch'
      env.FEATURES_BRANCH = 'feature-branch'
    break
  }
}
```

I need to read the values assigned to `env.ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH`, `env.HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION` and `env.FEATURES_BRANCH` within the default section of the case statement, so in this example I would like `feature-branch` returned for each variable.

Using a shell script, how can I get these values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Improved `case_to_var` script (Usage "*case_to_var filename*"):

```
#!/bin/sed -nf
# Only look at lines ending in ':'
/:$/{
    # remove leading `case`, spaces, and the ':', and save name.
    s/.* \|://g
    h
    # until the `break` line, recall name, append variable name, 
    # and make it shell-parsable.
    :foo g
        N
        y/./_/
        s/'//g
        s/ = /=/
        s/\n.*env//gp
        /break$/!b foo
}
```

Output of `case_to_var Jenkinsfile`:

```
develop_ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH=develop
develop_HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH=master
develop_FEATURES_BRANCH=master
master_ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH=develop
master_HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH=master
master_FEATURES_BRANCH=master
default_ECHO_CHAMBER_BRANCH=feature-branch
default_HENDRICKS_JS_INTEGRATION_BRANCH=feature-branch
default_FEATURES_BRANCH=feature-branch
```

Making the output shell parsable allows it to be executed and used; as with this cautious use of `eval`:

```
eval $(case_to_var Jenkinsfile)
echo $default_FEATURES_BRANCH $develop_FEATURES_BRANCH
```

Output:

```
feature-branch master
```

---

One-liner version:

```
sed -n '/:$/{s/.* \|://g;h;:foo g;N;y/./_/;s/'"'"'//g;s/ = /=/;s/\n.*env//gp;/break$/!b foo}' Jenkinsfile
```

Comment: thanks, would you mind explaining all the other options after `break`. I can see that you have removed `env` and `.`

Comment: When the variables have `env` it's not distinctive, and can be removed.

Comment: when you say careful use of `eval` would there be a safer way ? or is this ok ?

Comment: It's OK here.  As long as the programmer knows what `eval` does, (i.e. knows how the command line parses text), then controls exactly what's going into `eval`, it's safe and useful.  Using `eval` for unfiltered direct user input is not.